GDAL and OpenDAP
I am currently working on a project where we want to fetch meteorological data via a THREDDS server, using the OpenDAP protocol. We want to extract subsets of these, within a geographical location.
Having hard time finding out the best way to do this with GDAL:

The netCDF driver supports http, but will download the entire grid before anything can be done. This is too heavy for our purpose. Also, it does not support the DODS response from THREDDS.
The DODS driver is obsoleted in recent versions of GDAL.

What would be the best way to approach this, without pre-downloading everything ?
(Note: Using .NET Core / gdalnetcore)
